Code-Breaking Riddle
My friend sent me this puzzle.
I have a few 306-character strings of all seemingly random capital letters. Here are some examples:
FTCKKKGVKJEHIELTIAXEYLHWVZCVPXJBPVGHGCORGLZVBWCSCPBMRAMZGTBVJSPYETDPVFMVXHCRGMCJJKANJYRNPTIHHLPWBHGZRBRZOXXIUXVRSNQBEUDRSYFCZUAKEARENJONBLIVBCDFINFCQCUVJXEFCYHOYWFYQODBPLYBGTSLBJTVVPNBXWEXNYBCGODJREFNJWRCRUTKFLZVQOBNBEYZOHANOHZRTHZETRZJPAUFUKRCZIPOYRBLOPLXQDXHBZIJDXTHMRXVAVEISDVEQOTWLUEFFJTLNLRZLASRDNFZCB
FTCKEFYDPZCXEXNXLYVXGNWVGFYBDNKZYCQWECYYHUMJXLYPBVCLFPFOOMDWGXEFPYULMGGVDFOSNYMHFFKEDUDEKONDAMTWFHEGRSIWBMQCCLDMMXVKYQIMLALFDYAUBXYTRTRMNARHDZQDIOIRWSQHCPUZZKVSVCTFDNDLRRMGCBPTTMDDDXNZNSOEOUNGHAUJYXYWLFNKQXHHOEQGKFEQBWLXRBRZTUIOGBMGYBSJOXBGUAJHTTFPGQVLHQNUNCHDTMNQUAHZWBIIPABUEVAFPHZEBJAVLSWKFNOMXAQCYXBLZA
FTCKQDUYCLAXMQSIFAPLFBXGIIMEKQRRQVVHDMUKIBPMIFRBDUZFOMHEMWUJHIGCWOHJRLKKNOCXOJMLLTTRNOPQYZCMYQTEPFLNQGZAFOILVYCLCQYNZZPTCEQIFNOYDSMQLYDPGQUOCIHQPIALHYXXCBTNAHXSTLMWHEIIWNUBGLLJNGUDTUYJGWVYFAHPAEXVKETTIIANFCUGZBCWRJDXUOPGFWGJDEWUHDPIDODJHIEPJGQELOFXRMYFXIBAQNKIGZLAGYJLINSEOXPWXDESSRVMUEEDNORKEWPZWJTZXOTNMA
FTCKEBGVZTVEKYDLTZWMMQTSYSYCHVEZGJCWGYPHLGCSQWVMWTUZKNTKITLELOKSMSHORUWTHHFXOGIDKJNRSMKYZPHLLNCKTXWAQMOQDUAXKHXTESCHYKSKNLSKFXWLQYZEFUKJOCJKARALSJGBCSIZHBXDAZXEWXOUKDZWVCKHXVANHQISWFTBMTIKGOAHZXWYKHGEJWJURIMZSGHWZRCXHIKODXJOVALNOUOAESPBEMSKYRDTOAGTLLYEKHTAMTCEOJKXFMLWKJVMQOGZNZYNKFLAKSBKAKERVGNYHDAIQEKKLA
FTCKQNXYVENHJNHTLIMPXRQMKMWHHFTJNHXATUVVVWKBXKTPEMWOMSZZBPXRBSCBGPZFTYEYGNSMQRAHHMCGLGQNYLHSNCSSQPLXYQQMJYUKQHJAELDUOQZLDUKIRIVXCMQDYXWLGWFXZZQPZJUIODBKPWAKXHAKSMNUJNINKDTDNIOKXBVTZNAQMLGNUOABXUHJOMGUQIFRMYOLIVGNPGGOYPHCQUNHJDCBDGJSXKBPVHKPFRJQICPMYRKDWJCVPRDSBCODEEIIKVLILOBHQRBRVPGLNBJOFVIMKWUQVUXZLONXBC
Apparently, the codes are encoding nearly identical information, so I was thinking it could be a hash or something, but I don't know of any hashes this long.
Any ideas for solving this/reverse engineering them would be appreciated.

A hash may have infinite number of character strings that will produce the same value - thus it is not clear what you mean by code.
